# Using IS NULL in a WHERE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
 [dbo].[StoreProc1]
 (
 @Name varchar(10) = NULL,
 @Age int
 )

 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Name = @Name and Age = @Age
```

However, since `@Name = NULL` is incorrect, The stored procedure doesn't know if the input for `Name` was Null or Not to do `Name IS NULL` or `Name = '<value>'`

What's the quick work-around this?

I suppose i can do something like this, but isn't there an easier way?

```
IF @Name IS NULL 
BEGIN 
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME IS NULL AND AGE=@AGE
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME=@NAME AND AGE=@AGE
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[dbo].[StoreProc1]
 (
 @Name varchar(10) = NULL,
 @Age int
 )

 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (Name = @Name OR COALESCE(Name, @Name) IS NULL) and Age = @Age
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `Name = @Name` into:

```
( Name = @Name OR Name IS NULL AND @Name IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to get the results when name = @Name or when they are both null, then I would go with the following.

```
[dbo].[StoreProc1]
(
 @Name varchar(10) = NULL,
 @Age int
)

 SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE 
  WHERE (Name = @Name 
         OR ( Name IS NULL AND @Name IS NULL) )
    AND Age = @Age
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ISNULL(NAME,'')=ISNULL(@NAME,'') AND AGE=@AGE
```

Comment: This has a problem that NULL and '' get treated equivalently in Name/@Name